# charmap error while printing persian in python

Tags: python

I'm writing a telegram bot and I want it to work with Persian/farsi characters, I use VS Code.
I couldn't find the answer on the internet
and my code was like this

```
print('سلام')
```

when someone sends something like this to my bot it should answer it but the error is:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 0-3: character maps to <undefined>
```

it makes me mad, I have no idea what to do, i set my encoding method on VS Code as 'utf-8' but it didn't work.  please help me

Comment: you don't have to express emotion over the question - it's not relevant. what python version are you using?

Comment: I use python 3.8

Comment: try adding `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` as the *first* line of your file

Comment: actually - it's unclear where this error is coming from. Try adding some code that demonstrate the problem. And also show the full stacktrace and the line it reference.